# How can I find a stochastic process $A_t$ s.t. $\frac{1}{S_t}=\mathcal{E}(A)_t$?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

> Let $\mu, \sigma$ be constants and $(B_t)_t$ a brownian motion and define the process $S_t=S_0e^{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t+\sigma B_t}$. Then define $U_t=\frac{1}{S_t}$. I want to find a process $(A_t)$ s.t. $U_t=\mathcal{E}(A)_t$. Where $\mathcal{E}(A)_t$ denotes the stochastic exponential.

My idea was the following:

I know that $S_t$ solves the SDE $dS_t=\mu S_t dt+\sigma S_tdB_t$. And I also know that for a general process $(X_t)$ we have $\mathcal{E}(X)_t=\exp\left(X_t-\frac{1}{2}\langle X\rangle_t\right)$ which solves the SDE  $\mathcal{E}(X)_t=\mathcal{E}(X)_0+\int_0^t \mathcal{E}(X)_s dX_s~~(1)$.

Now let me define $f(x,s)=\frac{1}{x}$ then $\partial_xf(x,s)=-\frac{1}{x^2}$, $\partial_{xx}f(x,s)=\frac{2}{x^3}$, $\partial_sf(x,s)=0$. So by Itos formula we get $$\begin{align}U_t&=f(S_0,0)+\int_0^t \partial_xf(S_s,s)dS_s+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\partial_{xx}f(S_s,s)d\langle S\rangle_s\\&=\frac{1}{S_0}-\mu \int_0^t f(S_s,s)ds+\sigma \int_0^tf(S_s,s)dB_s+\sigma^2 \int_0^t f(S_s,s)ds\\&=f(S_0,0)-(\mu-\sigma^2)\int_0^tf(S_s,s)ds-\sigma \int_0^t f(S_s,s)dB_s\\\end{align}$$
Now my idea was to define $dA_t=-(\mu-\sigma^2)dt-\sigma dB_t$ because then we can rewrite $f(S_t,t)=f(S_0,0)+\int_0^tf(S_s,s)dA_s$ and hence we know by the "characterisation" of stochastic exponential $(1)$ that $U_t=f(S_t,t)=\mathcal{E}(A)_t$.

But does this idea work or am I wrong?

Comment: 1) You probably meant $\mu - \sigma^2/2$, not $(\mu-\sigma/2)^2$, didn't you? 2) Your derivation is correct, but it is perhaps easier to observe that $1/S_t=e^{-(\mu - \sigma^2/2) t - \sigma B_t}/S_0$ and use the Ito formula for $e^x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

You are overthinking it. First let me remark that the solution of the SDE $dS_t=\mu S_t\,dt+\sigma S_t\,dB_t$ is
$$
S_t=S_0\,e^{\mu t-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t+\sigma B_t}
$$
which differs from your  $S_t\,.$
Then,
$$
\textstyle U_t=\frac1{S_t}=\frac1{S_0}e^{-\mu t+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t-\sigma B_t}\,.
$$
With your definition ${\cal E}(X)_t=e^{X_t-\langle X\rangle_t/2}$ we can obviously choose
$$
X_t=-\log S_0-\mu t+\sigma^2t-\sigma B_t\,
$$ to have $U_t={\cal E}(X)_t\,.$

Comment: but it is the same only a bit overthought right?

Comment: @user123234 I do not want to unravel your Ito calculations. If you think they lead anywhere you might want to show that you arrive at the same $X\,.$

Comment: sure but I mean $dX_t=-(\mu -\sigma^2)dt-\sigma dB_t$ which is exactly my $dA_t$ or am I wrong?

Comment: Looks right! $\phantom{.}$